# Help with Logo identification on bridge rectifier

Tags: identification, bridge-rectifier

[image]

I am trying to identify this bridge rectifier. It is on a control board for a horizontal saw.  It is between the single phase 80 VA step down transformer 26 V output and the logic circuit.  There is no power on the DC side and the AC side reads 80 VAC using a multimeter.
I need to investigate a little more to find out why the transformer is outputting such a high voltage - likely the cause of the bridge-rectifier failure.

Comment: Does it really need to be identified?

Comment: I plan on replacing the component- so identifying the original and obtaining the data sheet will make sure the replacement is compatible.

Comment: Almost anything in the same size package should have comparable specs.

Comment: The generic part number is RS35. Then you have a voltage rating of 400,600,800,1000V. 400V is adequate for your application. Overvoltage tends to make the bridge rectifier go short circuit. Failing open circuit would be unusual but not unheard of.

Answer (score 1):

All bridge rectifiers used in Power Supply products have the same pinout.

You don't really actually need to identify the manufacturer.

Desolder it and test it by a multimeter. There are 4 diodes inside. If the part is not damaged then all 4 diodes will show 0.5 V to 0.7 V.